# Set up an Onclick event handler by HTML for undo link

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set up and write an onclick event handler **by HTML** for the undo link. Delete the last ordered item for every clicking of the undo link and update total quantity. And cancel the onclick event at the end of the event handler (i.e. clicking the link will not go to any destination, not even an internal link).

How should I modify my script to make these possible? Thanks!

```
<div id="Sushi" class="tabcontent">
   <form action="#" method="get">
      <table border="0" style="width:100%">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <img src="sushi-1.jpg" id="su1-img" title="Sushi Set A">
               <input id="su1-qty" type="number" name="input" placeholder="1" style="width:50px; height:20px">
               <input id="su1" type="submit" class="button" value="Add" name="Add" style="width:55px; height:25px">
            </td>
            <td>
               <img src="sushi-2.jpg" id="su2-img" title="Sushi Set B">
               <input id="su2-qty" type="number" name="input" placeholder="1" style="width:50px; height:20px">
               <input id="su2" type="submit" class="button" value="Add" name="Add" style="width:55px; height:25px">
            </td>
            <td>
               <img src="sushi-3.jpg" id="su3-img" title="Sushi Set C" width="125" height="135">
               <input id="su3-qty" type="number" name="input" placeholder="1" style="width:50px; height:20px">
               <input id="su3" type="submit" class="button" value="Add" name="Add" style="width:55px; height:25px">
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">
               <img src="sushi-4.jpg" id="su4-img" title="Sushi Set D">
               <input id="su4-qty" type="number" name="input" placeholder="1" style="width:50px; height:20px">
               <input id="su4" type="submit" class="button" value="Add" name="Add" style="width:55px; height:25px">
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </form>
</div>
<div id="Drinks" class="tabcontent">
   <form action="#" method="get">
      <table border="0" style="width:100%">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <img src="drink-1.jpg" id="dr1-img" title="Guava juice">
               <input id="dr1-qty" type="number" name="input" placeholder="1" style="width:50px; height:20px">
               <input id="dr1" type="submit" class="button" value="Add" name="Add" style="width:55px; height:25px">
            </td>
            <td>
               <img src="drink-2.jpg" id="dr2-img" title="Lemonade">
               <input id="dr2-qty" type="number" name="input" placeholder="1" style="width:50px; height:20px">
               <input id="dr2" type="submit" class="button" value="Add" name="Add" style="width:55px; height:25px">
            </td>
            <td>
               <img src="drink-3.jpg" id="dr3-img" title="Orange juice" width="125" height="135">
               <input id="dr3-qty" type="number" name="input" placeholder="1" style="width:50px; height:20px">
               <input id="dr3" type="submit" class="button" value="Add" name="Add" style="width:55px; height:25px">
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </form>
</div>
<div id="Dessert" class="tabcontent">
   <form action="#" method="get">
      <table border="0" style="width: 100%;">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <img src="dessert-1.jpg" id="de1-img" title="Raspberry cheese cake" width="140" height="125">
               <input id="de1-qty" type="number" name="input" placeholder="1" style="width:50px; height:20px">
               <input id="de1" type="submit" class="button" value="Add" name="Add" style="width:55px; height:25px">
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </form>
</div>
<div style="border:0px;" id="order">
   <center>
      <h2><b>Ordered Items</b></h2>
      14 Mar 2017 15:59
      <br><br>
      Table:4 - No. of Guests 3
      <table class="nth-table" id="orderlist" border="1">
         <thread>
            <tr>
               <th>Description</th>
               <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>
         </thread>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
         <tfoot>
            <tr>
               <td align="left"><strong>Total</strong></td>
               <td align="right" id="val"><strong></strong></td>
            </tr>
         </tfoot>
      </table>
      <br>
      <div class="noPrint">
         <a href="Order.html">undo</a>
      </div>
   </center>
   <br>
</div>

<script>
var total = 0;

function registerHandlers() {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
    [].slice.call(buttons).forEach(function(button) {
        button.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
    });
}

function onClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var button = event.target;
    var id = button.id;
    var desc = document.getElementById(id + '-img').getAttribute('title');
    var qty = document.getElementById(id + '-qty').value;
    total += parseInt(qty)
    addToTable(desc, qty);
}

function addToTable(desc, qty) {
    var row = '<tr><td align="left">' + desc + '</td><td align="right">' + qty + '</td></tr>';
    var tbody = document.querySelector('#orderlist tbody');
    tbody.innerHTML = tbody.innerHTML + row;
    document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = total;
}

registerHandlers();
</script>
```

Comment: why are you asking same question again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099565/calculate-total-quantity-when-a-table-is-updated-with-a-new-or-deleted-entry-by/59099721#59099721

Comment: @HiteshTripathi It is because I want to have it done by Onclick event handler by HTML instead of Javascript. Any methods?

Comment: Tangential to your main question, but `<center>` ? This presentational element was deprecated over a decade ago.

Comment: @RouninsaysJesuisMonica I know what you mean but I couldn't make a way to have my table align in the middle. How can I do that?

Comment: With `#order {display: flex; justify-content: center;}`

Answer (score 1):

The procedure for adding any event handler to any element is always the same.

There are three steps:

1. Grab the element
2. Declare the function
3. Attach the `EventListener` to the element, including the callback which references the declared function

Here is an example:

```
// GRAB THE ELEMENT
const myUndoLink = document.getElementsByClassName('my-undo-link')[0];

// DECLARE THE FUNCTION
const myUndoFunction = () => {

  [... FUNCTION HERE...]

}

// ATTACH THE EVENT LISTENER TO THE ELEMENT
myUndoLink.addEventListener('click'), myUndoFunction, false);
```

Comment: Do you mind telling me how is it like to apply event handler by HTML and Javascript respectively? Such that there will be 2 method for me to apply to the button. Thanks. @RouninsaysJesuisMonica

Comment: I'm not following. Can you restate your question? `EventHandlers` are attached to `DOM Elements` using javascript.